# How can i random.choice a question without the answer for a discord robot quiz game?

Tags: python, string, discord, tuples

I just started learning how to code ( in python ) and i was wondering how can I randomly ask questions for a quiz without the answer that follows?

For example, I'd want the robot to ask 'What's the capital of France?' but without it saying 'Paris'?

questions = [("What's the capital of France?", "Paris"), ("Who painted the Mona Lisa?", "Da Vinci")]

Ty :)

Comment: maybe change to `{What's the capital of France?": "Paris", "Who painted the Mona Lisa?":"Da Vinci"}` and then do random.random(questions.keys()) something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.choice` will just return a tuple (since those are the items in your list). So you can access just the first element while printing by doing `[0]`.

For example, `print(random.choice(questions)[0])`.

In the larger program you'd want to assign the tuple to a variable, so that later you fetch the answer for the same question (by using `[1]`) instead of randomly selecting again.